# JQuery Highlight is not working

Tags: jquery

i have the following references to jquery on my page:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the code within the

```
 $('#goStep2btn').click(function () {

 if (haserrors == true) {
        //alert("Displaying Error Message");
        $('#ErrDisplay').html(errortext);
        window.scrollBy(0, -600);
        $('#ErrDisplayContainer').slideDown({
            duration: 100
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            queue: false
        });

        //  $('ErrDisplayContainer').animateHighlight();

        $('ErrDisplayContainer').effect('highlight', { color: "#FF0000" }, 3000);
    }
    else if (haserrors == false) {
        //alert("no ERRORS");
        //format personal details and display
        $('#PersonalDetailsContainer').slideUp({
            duration: 200
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            queue: false
        });
        $('#jq_PersonalDetailsDisplay').slideDown({
            duration: 200
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            queue: false
        });
}

}
```

the button click event has alot more coding in it which validates the user input for registration step 1 before it gives the user an overview of the entered data and then shows step 2 for them to enter their payment information, if there are any errors with the data entered in step 1 the button validation will then show an Error Div tag and i want the div tag to highlight to alert the user that there are issues with the data that need addressing.

could anyone guide me as im quite new to jquery.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried looking at [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) plugin?

Comment: the validation works fine, it the

$('ErrDisplayContainer').effect('highlight', { color: "#FF0000" }, 3000);

that doesnt work

Comment: could it be that you are missing the id indicator in $('ErrDisplayContainer').effect ? It should be #ErrDisplayContainer

Comment: thanks!!! i am quite new to jquery so looking for # as id indicators is something that will eventually get imprinted into my debugging traits :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ErrDisplayContainer')
```

The above selector will match an `ErrDisplayContainer` element.  This is essencially:

```
<ErrDisplayContainer></ErrDisplayContainer>
```

Which I assume is not in your html.  What you are likely trying to match is the `id`:

```
$('#ErrDisplayContainer')
```

You're missing the `#`.